# How to get a static reference to a range of cells which will dynamically update?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-formula

I want to output the range of cells once found by a selection.

The range might be: `Q3:T31`

But when I add a column to the left of Q3, then I want the output should change to `R3:U31`

Similarly, if I add a row inside the range, I want the output to take that into account, and automatically update to: `Q3:T32`

PS: This is for use in a script. If you have another way of getting such a dynamically updating reference into the script, then by all means post it. I don't want to statically type 'Q3:T31' into the script, since columns or rows might be added to the spreadsheet which would invalidate that reference.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

`=ADDRESS(ROW(Q3);COLUMN(Q3);4;TRUE)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(T31);COLUMN(T31);4;TRUE)`

It will be a static reference to the range `Q3:T31` but will dynamically change when you add rows and columns to the spreadsheet which affect that range.